# VBScript Error: "Entry not found in index..." when opening documents Lotus Notes

Tags: vbscript, lotus-notes

Here is a working script for extract attachments from Lotus Notes letters:

```
Dim s
s = 1
Do 
s = s + 1
Dim Session 
Dim Maildb 
Dim view 
Dim vc
Dim doc 
Dim Item
Dim coll  
Dim x 
Dim Sender
Dim sentTo
Dim viewTimer
Dim ws
Dim Source
Set Session = CreateObject("Lotus.NotesSession") 
Call Session.Initialize("password") 
Set Maildb = Session.GetDatabase("DOMAIN/Servers/Server-Name/RU", "GroupMail\mailbox.nsf") 
Set view = Maildb.GetView("($inbox)") 


If Not Maildb.IsOpen = True Then 
  Call Maildb.Open 
End If 

With view 
  x = 0 
  ReDim LmailID(x) 
  ReDim HasAttach(x) 
  Set doc = .GetFirstDocument
  If doc Is Nothing Then

  else

    Call doc.PutInFolder("Processed")
    Call doc.Removefromfolder("($inbox)")

      Do 
        fileNames = Session.Evaluate("@AttachmentNames", doc) 

        For Each Filename In fileNames 

          Sender = doc.GETITEMVALUE("From")(0)
          strSearchForSpecificName = "SpecificName"
          If InStr(1, Sender, strSearchForSpecificName) > 0 then
            sentTo = "SpecificName@mail.ru"
          else 
            sentTo = Sender
          End If

          If Filename <> "" Then 
            Call doc.Save( False, False, True )
            Set NotesEmbeddedObject = doc.GetAttachment(FileName)
            NotesEmbeddedObject.ExtractFile ("d:\#files\" + Right("0" & Month(Now), 2) & "-" & Right("0" & Day(Now), 2) & "-"  & Year(Now) & "-" & Hour(Time) & Minute(time) & Second(time) & "_"  & Filename) 
            Set reply = doc.CreateReplyMessage( False )
            Call reply.replaceItemValue("SendTo", sentTo)
            Call reply.replaceItemValue("CopyTo", "copy@mail.ru")
            Call reply.replaceItemValue("Subject", "Re: " & "файл " + Filename + " передан в обработку " + Right("0" & Month(Now), 2) & "-" & Right("0" & Day(Now), 2) & "-"  & Year(Now) & Hour(Time) & ":" & Minute(time) & ":" & Second(time))
            doc.SaveMessageOnSend = True
            Call reply.Send( False )
          End If
        Next
        x = x + 1 
        ReDim Preserve LmailID(x) 
        Set doc = .GetNextDocument(doc) 

      Loop Until doc Is Nothing 
    End If
  End With 

  Wscript.Sleep (30 * 1000)

  Set Session = Nothing
  Set Maildb = Nothing 
  Set view = Nothing 
  Set vc = Nothing
  Set doc = Nothing 
  Set Item = Nothing
  Set coll = Nothing 
  Set x = Nothing

  s = s - 1
Loop While s > 0
```

The problem is that sometimes I'm getting an error: Error: "Entry not found in index..." and program stopped at *Set doc = .GetNextDocument(doc)* line. 
Is there there solution for resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is removing the first doc from the $Inbox, therefore it cannot be used as the anchor for getting the next document in $Inbox.  The solution would normally be to make sure that you get the next document *before* you remove the current document.  I.e., change

```
Call doc.PutInFolder("Processed")
Call doc.Removefromfolder("($inbox)")
```

to

```
Call doc.PutInFolder("Processed")
set nextDoc = .getNextDocument(doc)
Call doc.Removefromfolder("($inbox)")
```

and change

```
Set doc = .GetNextDocument(doc)
```

to

```
set doc = nextDoc
```

However, your code with the putInFolder and RemoveFromFolder calls is not actually inside the loop, therefore only the first doc that you process will be moved to the Processed folder and nextDoc will not be properly set after the first iteration of the loop. If you really only want to move the first document to the Processed folder, then the above solution still isn't right because you'll only be setting nextDoc once, outside the loop and you will have an infinite loop since you'll always be setting doc to the same nextDoc value.  You'll need another instance of `nextDoc = getNextDocument(doc)` inside the loop. If you really want all documents to be moved to the Processed folder, then you just need to move the entire block of code dealing with the folders *and* assigning nextDoc into the inside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple: The document is removed from Inbox and therefor is not in the index anymore. This happens if one of two conditions are true:

1. The NotesView- Property "AutoUpdate" is set to true
2. Your timer- triggered "refreshView"- sub (that is not in your example code) does a view.Refresh.

Despite of the fact, that in your code there is a lot of "nonsense" (sorry to say), it is easy to fix this code:

Just use the fact, that the view- object can be updated as advantage and change to "getfirstdocument" all the time:

Change this line:

```
Set doc = .GetNextDocument(doc)
```

to these lines:

```
Call .Refresh()
Set doc = .GetFirstDocument
```

What does this do: The `Refresh` removes the currently processed document from the view. The "next" document will be the first in view. And that one you get until there is no more "first" document...

And: Richard is right. You need to move the two rows `Call doc.PutInFolder("Processed")
    Call doc.Removefromfolder("($inbox)")` below the `Do` in order to move ALL documents to the folder and not only the first one.

Comment: Now new error: Object doesn't support this property or method "GetFirstDocument"

Comment: Sorry, GetFirstDocument does not have a parameter, and as this is inside of a "With", you can omit view. Check fixed code above